# Swift - Reload view with new data programmatically

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a MainView with some buttons. If a user for example presses button 1, I do navigate to a DetailView through a segue and where I programmatically add items to the view. The user can then press next, what I would like to do when this happens is to basically clear the DetailView and programmatically add new items that are customized to button 2 in the DetailView and when the user presses next clear DetailView again and programmatically add new items that are customized to button 3 etc...

From the MainView with the buttons I use this segue to navigate to the DetailView

```
func btnNext_Clicked(sender:UIButton){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetailView", sender: buttonId)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailView" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        detailViewController.buttonId = buttonId!
    }
}
```

But now I´m not sure how to clear the detailView and add new items when the user presses "Next". Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to remove old buttons, and create new programmatically, feel free to use something like

```
view.subviews.map({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

This will remove all subviews and you will be able to create new.